# Codeigniter 2.1 - multiple file upload doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have bit of a problem. When I select to upload one image, function works. But for the multiple images it doesn't work and I get error

> You did not select a file to upload.

(Fields for more images upload are created via JS, if user enter correct code. If code is not entered or if it is wrong original input is used for selecting a file).
What seems to be a problem?

Controller function:

```
function img_upload($folder) {
        $this->path = './public/img/' . $folder;
        $imgs = array();        
        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'upload_path' => $this->path
        );
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('upload', $config);

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {

            if (!$CI->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                return $error = implode(',',array('error' => $CI->upload->display_errors()));
            } else {
                $q = $CI->upload->data();
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $this->path . '/' . $q['file_name'];
                $config['new_image'] = $this->path . '/thumbs';
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 128;
                $config['height'] = 128;

                $CI->load->library('image_lib');
                $CI->image_lib->clear();
                $CI->image_lib->initialize($config); 
                $CI->image_lib->resize();                       
                array_push($imgs, $q['file_name']);
            }      
        }

        if(empty($imgs)){
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return implode(',', $imgs);
        }
    }
```

Part of HTML for selecting file:

```
<label for="image">Slika</label><input type="file" name="userfile" id="image" />
```

JS for adding new fields:

```
code.on('focusout', function(){
       if(!$(this).val())
           {
              $('label[for^=image_paid], input[id^=image_paid], input[name=time]').remove();                              
           }
       if(!$('#image4').length > 0)
           {$.ajax({
           type: 'POST', 
           url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>global_info/gi_get_ad_payment_code',
           data: 'code=' + code.val(),
           success: function(data){
             for(i = 1; i<=4; i++)
            {
               $('#image').after('<label for="image' + i +'">Slika</label><input type="file" name="userfile" id="image' + i +'" />');
            }  
            code.after('<input type="hidden" name="time" value="'+ data +'" />');            
            code.after('<input type="hidden" name="paid" value="1" />');            
           },
           error: function(){
               alert('nije uspeh');
           }
        }); /* KRAJ NA AJAX */
        };/* KRAJ NA IF */        
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't mind use this plugin. It will work great....I have used it many times ..http://www.plupload.com/